# JSON get with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, url

I have this URL: http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/2014/01/23/surfujpametno-aplikacija-za-android/?json=get_all_posts

I want to get content form that URL with JS. I read about it and I saw something about origin policy. Do I need that?
Could you write some small example how to get some content from this type of URL

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. It would be great if you could put some more effort into your question by showing your failed attempts to achieve what you want. be specific about what exactly has failed. Asking for a copy&pastable snippet will most likely lead to users ignoring your question. Also you're using tags that have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Since you correctly tagged this post, you obviously know what technologies you'll be needing to get this done. Please do some research first and don't hesitate to post your questions, should your efforts not yield the envisioned results

Answer (score 2):

You can use **getJSON** from jQuery library: [see here for more informations](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and parsed callback data.

```
$.getJSON("http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/2014/01/23/surfujpametno-aplikacija-za-android/?json=get_all_posts", function( data ) {

  // parse your data
});
```

or:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/2014/01/23/surfujpametno-aplikacija-za-android/?json=get_all_posts",
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {

      // parse your data
   },
});
```

If you need cross-origin request use **jsonp** parameter.

Comment: Why are you recommending one function but giving a demonstration of another?

Comment: No. I posted that comment on your answer. The answer had to exist before I could comment on it. Even if that was the case, I don't see how it could cause the first sentence of your answer to be able something different to the code example that forms the last paragraph.

Comment: This code doesn't work anyway. It complains that `data` is not defined. If I fix that, then it complains about it being a cross-origin request.

Comment: @Quentin ... what's your problem? I've posted my answer. This is a jQuery example from official documentation!

Comment: Sure, this code works only on "surfujpametno" domain. If you want to get this JSON from another domain you needs jsonp (cross origin request).

Comment: Since the question mentions the same origin policy, it's quite likely that he does want that. (And you don't *need* JSONP to deal with cross-origin requests, there are a few different work arounds).

Comment: Sure, there are more different workarounds to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://surfujpametno.roditelji.me/2014/01/23/surfujpametno-aplikacija-za-android/?json=get_all_posts',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    do_things(data);
  },
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It throws a syntax error. If I fix that, then it complains about it being a cross origin request. http://jsbin.com/mamaj/1/

Comment: After your edits, you still have a syntax error. And this is just a chunk of code. How about explaining what you've done.

Comment: Syntax error fixed.  Lots of answers to much less trivial questions than this have far worse explanations.  You have enough rep to edit it, if it's bothering you do the research and fix it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery's `ajax` with JSONP to get past origin policy problems

http://jsfiddle.net/Sam88/DkLUL/

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: url,
   async: false,
   jsonpCallback: 'callback',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(json) {
      console.log(json.status);
   },
   error: function(e) {
      console.log(e.message);
   }
});
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: `contentType: "application/json",` makes no sense. It is a GET request, you don't have a request body to specify the content-type of.

Comment: sorry about that, it was just a standard jsonp call, didn't think it mattered

Comment: sorry, copy pasted it from an example, you are right, that part is useless